# secure use of psexec?

Tags: authentication, network, windows, tools

As of March 7, 2014 PsExec now "encrypts all communication between local and remote systems, including the transmission of command information such as the user name and password under which the remote program executes."

With that said I still have security issue. If I use PsExec to remotely execute a script on my entire network it will be done using a highly privileged account. Those credentials will remain in memory of each of the workstations Il run the script on. If one of those workstations is infected with malware it can be problematic.  Is there any way to avoid this? If I run PsExec using the system parameter will it still hold my domain account credentials?  Is there any way that my credentials won't be saved in memory using PsExec?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by credentials staying in memory?  Which credentials: your username/password or the token used by the privileged account?

Comment: the nt hash(password) for the priviliged domain account.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered at [SANS' forensic blog](http://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2012/12/17/protecting-privileged-domain-accounts-psexec-deep-dive) in the comments section, here is the excerpt:

**QUESTION**

> Are not you running all the commands in this article on your trusted
>   workstation?

**ANSWER**

> Yes, I'm running them on my trusted machine. However, if I run 'psexec -u' from my trusted machine, it sends the password to the
>   remote untrusted machine and performs an interactive logon. We need to
>   avoid this. So one workaround was to use RunAs to lunch a new command
>   shell as my privileged account on my trusted machine and then logon
>   using psexec without '-u'. This avoids sending the password and
>   creating the interactive logon on the remote untrusted host.

**QUESTION**

> Are not your hashes going to untrusted machine with runAs?

**ANSWER**

> Not in the scenario I just described, because I would be authenticating with a network logon.

**QUESTION**

> are your hashes will stored on your trusted workstation or where?

**ANSWER**

> Yes, the hashes of my privileged account will be stored on my local trusted workstation once I use RunAs to start a command shell as
>   that user.

**QUESTION**

> How a workaroud is that I coudlnt get it.

**ANSWER**

> If you're asking why it is a workaround, it's a workaround in the sense that I can connect to a remote machine using a privileged
>   account without having to use the '-u' option. Instead it uses the
>   credentials of the currently logged on privileged user within the
>   RunAs session.

Comment: So based on that if i will use 'runas' to run psexec from my workstation to a remote untrusted machine.the hashes of the priviliged user will be stored locally on my workstation and the script will run using currently logged on privileged user... ? which that will be... ?  if i will use -s parameter will that priviliged user be nt autority\system ?

Comment: This only really works if the systems are on the same domain. (Looks like your case is - just adding the comment in case future people needing this answer don't have that.) Otherwise, you'll need to send credentials (or a hash) to the target for authentication and you're back in the same boat.